# Link and Flatten PairRDD based on common element in key or value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of Pairs as below :

```
(a,b)
(b,c)
(e,d)
(f,d)
(g,f)
```

I would like to find items that can be linked together based on either the key or value, flatten them and create a sorted RDD. For example after the 
transformation the new RDD will be :

```
(a,b,c) - As (a,b) and (b,c) can be linked by common element "b"
(d,e,f,g) - As (e,d) and (f,d) is linked by "d", (f,d) and (g,f) is linked by "f"
```

For an input like :

```
(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(a,d),(c,e)
```

The output should be:

```
(a,b,c,d,e) - As all the pairs are connected by either the key or value with some other pair
```

Appreciate any ideas on implementing a scalable solution for this using Apache Spark.

Comment: Does the order matter i.e. `(e,d), (a,b), (b,c),(f,d), (g,f)` should return the same result as what you gave?

Answer (score 2):

You are describing [connected commponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29), and [graphx provides an implementation of this in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components).